# Seamless authentication for sharepoint site in intranet network

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

We have SharePoint 2016 farm with 8 servers also the load balancer server is functioning to balance the request between the web-front-end server(s).  The web application is configured to use the ADFS as an additional authentication provider while the default is "Windows Authentication NTLM" also using at the same time in the default zone.  As web application has two authentication provider ADFS and Windows here every time user have to select the authentication method. if window auth is selected user will enter there internal Active directory account manually to login into and if the user selects ADFS, request goto adfs and redirected to Azure login as relying party and a claim is configured. The ADFS thing is ok for me as it is working on expectations.

But I want to resolve the intranet users in intranet network itself (Pass-through Authentication). As we know ADFS has the capability to authenticate intranet user in company network by setting up adfs property by Set-AdfsProperties -IntranetUseLocalClaimsProvider $true to have all intranet users use AD and not be redirected to Azure AD but somehow it's not affecting anything, cmd is run successfully but not working.

Is there any additional configuration related to ADFS or SharePoint which needs to be done to archive pass-through authentication or autologin for intranet users which has logged into the machine using AD account .?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design. You can workaround it with [SPByPassLoginPage](https://github.com/Yvand/SPBypassLoginPage/blob/master/README.md).

This farm solution works with SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016. It adds a page that allows SharePoint administrators to bypass provider selection page when multiple authentication modes are enabled in a zone of a web application.

Comment: Thank you for respond.
By-passing the provider selection requires to configure one method at least in the solution, either window or ADFS but is there any possibility to auto-detect and log in with the window without selecting the authentication method in intranet network and putting the windows credential.